# Split a string based on any number occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex

Using Regex how can I split a string based on number occurrence?

For example I have a string like below.

```
var text = "1 dozen 3 dozen 4 dozen kg";
```

I need to split it like,

**Expected Output:**

```
1 dozen   
3 dozen   
4 dozen kg
```

I tried the following regex,

```
var text = "1 dozen 3 dozen 4 dozen kg";
var regex = /(\d\s)/g;  // regex I tried
console.log(text.split(regex));
```

but end up with

> ["","1 ","dozen ","3 ","dozen ","4 ","dozen kg"]

Please help me on framing the `regex` and feel free to ask if my question is not clear.

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KCwLe/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `positive lookahead` based split call can do the job:

```
var arr = text.split(/\s*(?=\d+)/);
```

will give:

```
["1 dozen", "3 dozen", "4 dozen kg"]
```

**Explanation:** Breaking down this regex `/\s*(?=\d+)/`

```
\s*        - match 0 or more spaces
(?=\d+)    - Make sure previous match is immediately followed by 1 or more digits
\s*(?=\d+) - match 0 or more spaces if it is immediately followed by 1 or more digits
```

PS: `(?=\d+)` is actually a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: You could add `.slice(1)` after the split call to remove the first element.

Comment: @anuBhava +1 Nice.  Can you please add details/ explanation about your regex?   Regex is making my head to spin.

Comment: @user1671639: Added some explanation and a very good tutorial on positive lookahead.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use `match`?

```
var text = "1 dozen 3 dozen 4 dozen kg";
var regex = /\d\s\D+/g;
console.log(text.match(regex)); //=> ["1 dozen ", "3 dozen ", "4 dozen kg"]
```

Comment: You may want to replace `\D` with `[^\s\d]` or `\w`.  Otherwise you get those trailing spaces.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: Good point, not sure if OP needs them or not.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: replacing like that is not quite correct. It will return "4 dozen" instead of "4 dozen kg"

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Thanks for noticing the trailing space but no problem still know with spaces.

Comment: @elclanrs +1 If possible, can you please add some details about your regex?

Comment: What do you want to know about it exactly? If you want to get rid of the trailing spaces you can do this `text.match(regex).map(function(v){ return v.trim() })`

Comment: `\d+(?:\s+[^\d\s]+)+`  will match a number (one or more digits) followed by one or more words ("word" being defined as one or more non-digit, non-whitespace character).