# split string based on numeric substrings inside it

Tags: c++, string, split, substring

I've a string, e.g.

```
std::string input = "Trp80Ter";
```

and I need to split it taking the letters before and after the number value, obtaining:

```
std::string substring0 = "Trp";
std::string substring1 = "Ter";
int number = 80;
```

Moreover, it should be the FIRST number ocurrence inside the string, cause I can also have value as:

```
std::string input = "Arg305LeufsTer18";

// which I need to transform in:
std::string substring0 = "Arg";
std::string substring1 = "LeufsTer18";
int number = 305;
```

PS: my first "character" part of the string is not always 3 char long

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030608/split-a-string-based-on-any-number-occurrence) but is for JS, and I could find no answer searching the web

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
std::string input = "...";
std::string::size_type pos1 = input.find_first_of("0123456789");
std::string::size_type pos2 = input.find_first_not_of("0123456789", pos1);
std::string substring0 = input.substr(0, pos1);
std::string substring1 = input.substr(pos2);
int number = std::stoi(input.substr(pos1, pos2-pos1));
```

Alternatively, C++11 and later have a native [Regular Expression library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) for searching for patterns in strings.

Answer (score 0):

And here is a Spirit-based [solution](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pL7jhRIxC7XOTAzo):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

int main() {
    std::string input = "Arg305LeufsTer18";
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
    const auto first_str = +char_("A-Za-z");
    const auto second_str = +char_("A-Za-z0-9");
    std::tuple<std::string, int, std::string> out;
    parse(input.begin(), input.end(), first_str >> int_ >> second_str, out);

    std::cout << get<0>(out) << std::endl << get<1>(out) << std::endl << get<2>(out) << std::endl;
}
```